# Google Timezone API limits

Tags: python, linux, perl, timezone

I signed up for a google developer project. I activated the google timezone api. I added money to my project. Is it possible to make more than 2500 timezone requests a day? If so, how do I activate that? I'm currently limited to 2500/24hrs. I need 100,000/24hrs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about contractual concerns, not about the API and is better suited for Google's help channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Google Timezone API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/#Limits) it states that the 100,000/24hrs limit is for [Maps for Business](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/) customers.

Comment: Sorry about it being off topic.